# Ionic platform: "Resize ready" with debounce time pipe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to have a "resize ready" event with [Ionics platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform) resize event. I try to use rxjs debounceTime function to only have an event when the resize is done.

This is the code in the "ngOnInit" of my component

```
// Reset ingredients on resize ready
this.platform.resize.subscribe(async () => {
  console.log("Resize");
});

this.platform.resize.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(async () => {
  console.log("Resize ready");
});
```

"resize" is outputted a lot while resizing the window, like expected. And "Resize ready" is outputted when resize is done, like expected.

But:
Resize ready is outputted 12 times

[image]

Does somebody have an idea, why it is triggered 12 times? I expect it to only show once.

Comment: Can you post the full `ngOnInit` method? I suspect the subscription might be set up multiple times.

Comment: @pascalpuetz: Wow, you are completely right. I have the component 12 times on my current page :) Thank you! So everything is just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, easy solution: I had the component 12 times on my page, so everything is fine.

I will leave this solution online for persons search on how to have a "Resize ready" event for ionic.

Comment: It isn't really a solution since there wasn't a problem.

Comment: This is a solution, since this was a problem. Also, this is a common pitfall when handling observables. Hence this should be left here as a solution.